# What to use in pressure fermentation

Tags: fermentation, containers

I'm still pretty new to pressure fermentation and have been using it primarily to make sukimono - cabbage mixed with salt under pressure for about a day.

I would like to make a whole cabbage at a time or even a bit more, but I'm unsure what is the best container for this and a matching weight to close off the air.

Also, I would like to avoid plastics if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise if you are planning make often then I would invest in a gallon fermentation crock. It may cost you anywhere from $100- $200 but if you are making this often then i t maybe worthwhile for you as it will last you for many years and most come with weights already specific to the volume of the crock. My grandmother has one she uses for making kimchi

Comment: Would you by chance be able to supply a link to where I might purchase one of these online? More importantly, so even if I buy it elsewhere, I have an example to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Check out harsch crocks. Also, a tip for lacto-fermenting whole cabbage heads- carve out a bit of the core at the base and pack that area with salt prior to brining. It helps the bacteria get access to the inner cabbage layers. And use a few of the outer leaves as a lid under the weights. The outer leaves of organic cabbage have all the good bacteria on them. Never use supermarket veg, the sprays kill the good bacteria! Good luck

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the recommendation. Here's a link to the Harsch Crocks for other readers too: http://www.canningpantry.com/sauerkraut-crocks.html